# JSON_QUERY unable to handle NULL

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a table. Few columns are of String, Integer type. And few are JSON type. I am writing a query to form each row as a json object. I have issues with JSON_QUERY(jsondataColumnName). If the column is populated NULL JSON_QUERY fails.

I have already written query below.

```
select 
(
    SELECT     [customerReferenceNumber] as customerReferenceNumber
              ,[customerType] as customerType
              ,[personReferenceNumber] as personReferenceNumber
              ,[organisationReferenceNumber] as organisationReferenceNumber
              ,json_query(isnull(product,'')) as product 
              ,json_query(isnull([address],'')) as address 

  FROM [dbo].[customer] 
  FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS customer
from [dbo].[customer] P
```

> Msg 13609, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 0.

Comment: Can we see the json?

Answer (score 0):

By default, for `JSON` don't work with `NULL VALUES`. Use `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` to handle.

As Example:  `JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES) AS customer`

As reference:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/include-null-values-in-json-include-null-values-option?view=sql-server-ver15